# com.netflix.eureka.InstanceRegistry never evict stale instances

Tags: server, instances, netflix, evict

registred but died instances of services will not be evicted by the InstanceRegistry. The timer instance is started but the method isLeaseExpirationEnabled() always returns false.
this stems from these lines:

```
        boolean leaseExpirationEnabled = (numberOfRenewsPerMinThreshold > 0)
            && (getNumOfRenewsInLastMin() > numberOfRenewsPerMinThreshold);
```

Does anybody has an idea whats wrong with the picture?
Thanx for your help
Lutz